# How do I add a custom textinput field in an Apex Salesforce page?

Tags: input, salesforce, textfield, visualforce, apex-code

I have a page created with a form in Apex that outputs here: http://globalexperiences.com/general/contactus.php

I've created a new field in Leads (also in Accounts but that's moot) and am trying to call it to output a text field that someone can enter into. My code is this:

```
        <apex:outputLabel value="Skype Name: " for="inputSkypeName" />
            <apex:inputText id="inputSkypeName" value="{!lead.Skype_Name__c}" />
```

Whenever I try it with any other field I've created, it outputs the input field but for this one it just outputs the label only. I can't find any documentation on this anywhere. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<apex:inputField>` to produce editors for sObject fields. `apex:inputText` is used primarily for controller/extension properties. inputField also makes sure that non-text fields (such as lookups, dates, etc) get proper representation in rendered HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the field level security is setup correctly for this field.  It will need to be visible to the profile you are using to view the page.

Also, if you want a field like this to render properly, you 'll need to put  tags around it.

Answer (score 1):

Check field level security as suggested above and also check whether the user's profile has read/write access to the custom object in question — if they only have read access then the field will not be editable.

Answer (score 0):

In your Page Controller if you're using a custom controller or not using the Standard Controller make sure you're querying the field.